# If the pointwise ergodic theorem holds along all subsequences with nonzero natural density, is the system strong mixing?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\mathbf X := (X, \mathcal S, \mu, T)$ be an ergodic measure preserving system with finite measure such that for every increasing sequence $\{n_k\}$ of natural numbers whose [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#:%7E:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20natural%20density,n%20%5D%20as%20n%20grows%20large) exists and is positive, we have that for all $f \in L^1(X)$,

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} f(T^{n_i} x) \to \int_X f \, d\mu$$

as $n \to \infty$ for a.e. $x \in X$.

**Question:** Is $\mathbf X$ necessarily strong mixing?

Comment: The Chacon subshift in the answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47080/examples-of-transformations-which-are-weak-mixing-but-not-strong-mixing looks like a good candidate for a counterexample (though verifying the pointwise ergodic theorem may require a certain amount of combinatorial analysis).

Comment: ... unfortunately, the best known mixing rates for this shift (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.00823 ) are a little bit too slow to get the pointwise convergence from a van der Corput / Borel-Cantelli argument.  But if one can find a non-strongly mixing system which has a mixing rate faster than a large power of $1/\log N$ (rather than a small power) then I think one is in business.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One can construct a counterexample using a stationary Gaussian process.  The basic idea is to use a system that is weak mixing with very good bounds, without being strong mixing, as it is the former property that is enough to guarantee a pointwise ergodic theorem of the type you seek. Stationary Gaussian processes have the advantage of being tractable to compute with (everything is determined, in principle at least, from the autocorrelation function).  Also note that any counterexample must be at least weakly mixing, since a non-trivial eigenfunction $f \circ T = \lambda f$ of the process would lead to a failure of the pointwise ergodic theorem after restricting to shifts in a Bohr set such as $\{ n: |\lambda^n - 1| \leq 0.1 \}$.

Let $a_n$ be the sequence $a_n := 10^{10^n}$ (actually any sufficiently rapidly growing sequence would work here).  One can construct a stationary Gaussian process $(X_n)_{n \in {\bf Z}}$ as the limit in distribution (as $m \to \infty$) of the processes
$$ \left( 2^{-m/2} \sum_{\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_m \in \{0,1\}} Y_{n+\epsilon_1 a_1 + \dots + \epsilon_m a_m} \right)_{n \in {\bf Z}}$$
where $(Y_n)_{n \in {\bf Z}}$ an iid Gaussian process of mean zero and variance one.  One can check that the $X_n$ are well defined as a stationary, mean zero Gaussian process and that the autocorrelation function is
$$ \mathrm{Cov}(X_n, X_{n+h}) = 2^{-j}$$
when $h$ is of the form $h = \pm a_{i_1} \pm \dots \pm a_{i_j}$ for some $i_1 < \dots < i_j$, and
$$ \mathrm{Cov}(X_n, X_{n+h}) = 0$$
otherwise.  In particular, $X_n$ and $X_{n+h}$ are independent unless one is in the rare situation when $h$ is a signed sum of the $a_1,a_2,\dots$.

Since $\mathrm{Cov}(X_0, X_{a_i}) = 1/2$, the autocorrelation function fails to decay to zero, thus this process is not strongly mixing.

To show the pointwise ergodic theorem for a positive density sequence $n_1 < n_2 < \dots$, it suffices from the maximal ergodic theorem to do so assuming $f$ is some bounded function of a finite number of the $X_i$, and we can normalise $f$ to have mean zero.  Then $f$ and $f \circ T^h$ will be independent unless $h$ is of the form $\pm a_{i_1} \pm \dots \pm a_{i_j} + O(1)$ for some $i_1 < \dots < i_j$.  As this is a sparse set, we can obtain good weak mixing bounds of the form
$$ \sum_{h=-H}^H |\langle f \circ T^h, f \rangle| \ll 3^{\log_{10} \log_{10} H} \ll \log H \tag{1}$$
with our choice of $a_n = 10^{{10}^n}$.  (Actually even just the bound $H/\log^2 H$ would be enough for our application.)

We would like to show that $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f \circ T^{n_i}$ converges a.e. to zero.  By a standard approximation argument, it suffices to do so assuming that $N$ belongs to a lacunary sequence, e.g., $\lfloor (1+\varepsilon)^m \rfloor$ for $m=1,2,\dots$ and a fixed $\varepsilon>0$.  By the Borel-Cantelli lemma and Markov's inequality, it then suffices to obtain a bound of the shape
$$ \int_X |\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f \circ T^{n_i}|^2\ d\mu \ll \frac{1}{\log^2 N}$$
(say) for large $N$.  Opening up the square, and noting from positive density that $n_N \asymp N$, we can bound the LHS by
$$\ll \frac{1}{N} \sum_{h=-n_N}^{n_N} |\langle f \circ T^h, f \rangle|$$
and the claim follows from (1).

Comment: This was a very illustrative example of how to construct weakly mixing processes that are not strongly mixing. Just one question, could you give a short sketch on how the log bound in (1) is obtained? It is intuitive that it is logarithmic in $H$ because of the sparsity of $a_n$, but I was unable to derive it rigorously.

Comment: Ah, I needed to make the sequence a tiny bit sparser to get the pure logarthmic bound ($10^{10^n}$ rather than $100^{2^n}$).  That way there are only $O(\log_{10} \log_{10}) H$ different $a_i$ that can contribute to the signed sum, giving $O( 3^{\log_{10} \log_{10} H} ) = O(\log H)$ shifts that are not independent.